# Java - Google API - Publish a document

Tags: java, integration, google-docs-api

I have a problem uploading information using the Google Document API. The task is to upload a document, then publish it right after the upload. The first part I have solved, get a `DocsService` client, authenticate myself with `client.setUserCredentials(userName, password)` method, and then upload the content with `client.insert(URL, newDocument)`.

At this point the document appears in my Google folder. My problem is I can't figure out how too publish it. I tried to emulate the POST method (what Google creates when I click publish), but it didn't work. I also tried to use [this methodology](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PublishingRevisions), but I could not figure out how should I authenticate myself (using `client.setUserCredentials`).

Is there any simple way, or best practice for publishing via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing is done by modifying the document's ACL, more information can be found in the [developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_sharing_permissions_of_resources_via_access_control_lists_acls).

Using the Java client library, to make a document read-only for everybody, you can do:

```
AclEntry aclEntry = new AclEntry();
aclEntry.setRole(AclRole.READER);
aclEntry.setScope(new AclScope(AclScope.Type.DEFAULT, null));
URL url = new URL(documentEntry.getAclFeedLink().getHref);

return service.insert(url, aclEntry);
```