# How to publish Google Docs in .NET?

Tags: .net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm using the [google-gdata](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) .NET library for integrating with Google Docs. It's working out pretty well, but I can't figure out how to use it to [publish my documents](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37579&topic=1360911&ctx=topic) for view-only link-based web access.

The basic idea behind this is to be able to upload a document to Google Docs, and be able to view that document in a web environment (outside of Google) without having to log in using a Google credential. As far as I can tell, the best way to do that would be publishing it via a secret link, as described in the help article linked above.

So does anyone know how to publish Google Docs programatically in .NET?

#### EDIT

As a point of reference, and as an illustration on the difference between changing the ACL on a document (i.e. making it public) and publishing the document per se (as the link above describes), these are the corresponding versions of the same document on Google Docs:

- ACL public read access | http://bit.ly/HYAXBc
- Published to the web | http://bit.ly/HN0rEn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just updated the .NET client library, now you can use the following code to publish a revision (it assumes `entry` is the DocumentEntry instance you want to publish):

```
RevisionQuery revisionQuery = new RevisionQuery(entry.RevisionDocument);
RevisionFeed revisions = service.Query(revisionQuery);

// TODO: choose the revision you want to publish, this sample selects the first one
RevisionEntry revision = (RevisionEntry)revisions.Entries[0];

revision.Publish = true;
revision.PublishAuto = true;

revision.Update();
```

Comment: Your continued work on the library is very, very appreciated. Thanks for pushing out this update. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already been answered on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036474/1106381) which contains a Java code snippet.
For .NET, you should be able to do something like that:

```
AclEntry aclEntry = new AclEntry();
aclEntry.Role = new AclRole("reader");
aclEntry.Scope = new AclScope(AclScope.SCOPE_DEFAULT);

// documentEntry is the document that you want to publish and service is an 
// authorized DocumentsService object.
AclEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(
    new Uri(documentEntry.AccessControlList), aclEntry);
```

Comment: Publishing (at least in Google's terms) and controlling the document ACL seems to be two completely different things, although they're related. Modifying the ACL allows me to grant r/w access to any Google account, but "publishing" allows me to render a web version of the document, with a *public* link I (can) share out.

Comment: Once shared with the default scope (including anonymous access), you can use the document's alternate link to view the document on a web browser using `documentEntry.AlternateUri`. In the XML payload, the alternate link looks like this: ``<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=12345&hl=en"/>``.

Comment: Yeap, I know. You're still talking about the ACL component of Google Docs, but I'm asking about the publishing component of it. I know I can access a public document, or a document to which I've been given ACL read access to using a link, but this is completely different from publishing a Google Docs document, and viewing it **as published on the web**, and not as a Google Docs document. Try it out for yourself --- a published document functions a lot like a web page, while a Google Docs document looks like you're viewing a document in MS Word or something.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, you can publish a document by editing a document's revision as described [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#publishing_documents_by_publishing_a_single_revision). In .NET, it means retrieving a revision entry, adding/updating the docs:publish attributes and sending an UPDATE request for this entry.

Comment: Many thanks and props for pulling out the relevant documentation. Much appreciated. :) +1