# Bad Request when querying revisions

Tags: .net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to follow the instructions laid out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770896/how-to-publish-google-docs-in-net/10200031#10200031), but I'm not able to make it work.

The constructor for the RevisionQuery takes in a string, but the entry.RevisionDocument is a Uri.  I just used .ToString(), but now I'm getting an error - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request - when I try to execute the query (RevisionFeed revisions = service.Query(revisionQuery)).  The Uri is set to http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/document:{id}/revisions.  Is that the correct Uri for getting the revisions from a document?  When I go to the url in a browser, I get the same error.

I believe I've set up my service by using the proper credentials, but I'm sure I'm just missing something small.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have a number of docs that I need to publish, and doing them by hand would be quite painful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property entry.RevisionDocument is actually a string:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/documents3/documententry.cs#373

It can be used in the RevisionQuery constructor, as shown in the docs at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_revisions_of_documents_and_files, and as in the following snippet:

```
RevisionQuery revisionQuery = new RevisionQuery(entry.RevisionDocument);
RevisionFeed revisions = service.Query(revisionQuery);
```

Comment: I see what I'm doing wrong.  Instead of using Google.Data.Documents.DocumentEntry, I'm using Google.Documents.Document as my entry.  In that object the RequestDocument is a Uri, but in the DocumentEntry I can see that it's a string.  I knew it was something small that I was missing.  I'll refactor my code to use the Service/Query model rather than the DocumentRequest model and see what happens.  Thanks so much!