# upload file to google drive windows forms c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, windows-forms-designer

Basically the idea of ​​the program is as follows: The user enters their email account and password google drive, then select the file and click upload button.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to have an embedded browser to handle the authentication using OAuth, as the client will need to enter their credentials into the Google login page. A previous answer here [How to publish Google Docs in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770896/how-to-publish-google-docs-in-net) also indicates there is a .net library (which I havent tried) that might help.

Comment: but I have read about OAuth and says I need a "client id" and a "client secret" codes to connect to my google account drive, why would you need for each user? I am newbie in the subject and I may haven't understand.

Comment: Your Client ID and Client Secret are specific to your application, not specific to the users account. Basically the user must give your application rights to access their filestore and the Client ID and Client Secret are used to tell the user which applicaiton you are. Typically the scenario is that the applicaiton tries to access the users file store, this redirects to their login page which they use to login, then Google says "application MyApp is trying to access your files for Reading - do you want to allow this ?" they then say yes or no.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
Do you know any code example for a connection with this authorization google drive in C#? And how to upload a file?

Comment: I've not used it but you could try this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/dotnet